# Why animated image takes a moment to display clearly?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

Why image animated by jquery takes a moment to display clearly?

To understand problem here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAtce/)

Here when you click button image gets large and it takes a while to get image clear.

How to correct this problem?

Here is code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("#btn").click(function(){
                $("#im").animate({width:200,height:200});
         });
});
```

Comment: Your image is giving a 403 forbidden.  Also what browser is it having issues in?

Comment: Your browser is probably optimising the animation. (the browser probably cached the low-resolution version of the image in memory, but to get the higher resolution, it needs to re-decode it, and on top of that it probably won't until the image has been static for a moment). Try making your raw image 200x200 pixels (if it isn't already).

Comment: I really don't see the problem... please explain - [fiddle example edited](http://jsfiddle.net/TAtce/1/)

Comment: @ShlomiHassid try with this image: http://jsfiddle.net/TAtce/2/ After it has loaded, notice that after the animation it doesn't use antialiasing for a moment. I think this is what he's referring to. My thoughts weren't correct, but the solution I gave will fix it (and is why your image worked fine)

Comment: @Dave may be you are right, but how to solve this issue ?

Comment: @user1390378 just upload a copy of your image which is resized to 200x200 pixels (usually in big sites this is handled automatically by a server script, but it's easier to just edit the image in an image editor). Then use this smaller image for the thumbnail. You get the added benefit of faster page loads and less bandwidth too!

Comment: @Dave you are 100% right - tested twice with different images. but there is a trick two minutes please...

Comment: Summary: tried using css background instead- same!, tried using transition and .css()- same! even tried another contained and hidden image (in the target size) that show() it in the animate() callback function - same! @Dave you are right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is a browser optimization when asked to scale images quickly in an animation.  They are using a fast scaling algorithm during the animation to make the animation go quicker and are then using a more accurate scaling algorithm once the animation stops.

You can read about scaling algorithm changes here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56627

Also, here's some info on how different browsers scale images differently: http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/

Comment: Read the link I added to my answer and there may be some vendor-specific prefixes that let you control scaling algorithm or it may just be the way the browser behaves.